# WSO2ESB Proxy - Payload mediator auto population

Tags: java, xml, web-services, proxy, wso2-esb

I want to populate payload mediator with the response from a first service and this payload is going to be sent to another service. I used context expression and everything seems correct. But payload mediator is not getting populated. When the message built to send to the second service, payload remains blank. I used ctx path expression shown below to populate.

Here is the proxy service configuration,

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
       name="CreditProxy"
       transports="https,http"
       statistics="disable"
       trace="disable"
       startOnLoad="true">
   <target>
      <inSequence>
         <log level="full">
            <property name="sequence" value="inSequence - request for CreditProxy"/>
         </log>
         <property xmlns:sam="http://samples.esb.wso2.org"
                   name="ORG_ID"
                   expression="//sam:credit/sam:id"/>
         <property xmlns:sam="http://samples.esb.wso2.org"
                   name="ORG_AMOUNT"
                   expression="//sam:credit/sam:amount"/>
         <enrich>
            <source type="inline" clone="true">
               <sam:get xmlns:sam="http://samples.esb.wso2.org">
                  <sam:id>?</sam:id>
               </sam:get>
            </source>
            <target type="body"/>
         </enrich>
         <enrich>
            <source type="property" clone="true" property="ORG_ID"/>
            <target xmlns:sam="http://samples.esb.wso2.org" xpath="//sam:get/sam:id"/>
         </enrich>
         <log level="full">
            <property name="sequence" value="inSequence - request for PersonInfoService"/>
         </log>
         <property name="STATE" value="PERSON_INFO_REQUEST"/>
         <send>
            <endpoint>
               <address uri="http://127.0.0.1:9764/services/PersonInfoService/"/>
            </endpoint>
         </send>
      </inSequence>
      <outSequence>
         <log level="full"/>
         <property xmlns:ns="http://samples.esb.wso2.org"
                   xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"
                   xmlns:ax23="http://samples.esb.wso2.org/xsd"
                   name="address"
                   expression="/soapenv:Envelope/soapenv:Body/ns:getResponse/ns:return/ax23:address"
                   scope="default"
                   type="STRING"/>
         <property xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"
                   xmlns:ns="http://samples.esb.wso2.org"
                   xmlns:ax23="http://samples.esb.wso2.org/xsd"
                   name="id"
                   expression="/soapenv:Envelope/soapenv:Body/ns:getResponse/ns:return/ax23:id"
                   scope="default"
                   type="STRING"/>
         <property xmlns:ns="http://samples.esb.wso2.org"
                   xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"
                   xmlns:ax23="http://samples.esb.wso2.org/xsd"
                   name="name"
                   expression="/soapenv:Envelope/soapenv:Body/ns:getResponse/ns:return/ax23:name"
                   scope="default"
                   type="STRING"/>
         <payloadFactory media-type="xml">
            <format>
               <p:credit xmlns:p="http://samples.esb.wso2.org"><!--0 to 1 occurrence--><ax25:info xmlns:ax25="http://samples.esb.wso2.org"><!--0 to 1 occurrence--><xs:amount xmlns:xs="http://samples.esb.wso2.org/xsd">?</xs:amount>
                     <!--0 to 1 occurrence--><ax25:personInfo xmlns:ax25="http://samples.esb.wso2.org/xsd"><!--0 to 1 occurrence--><xs:address xmlns:xs="http://samples.esb.wso2.org/xsd">$1</xs:address>
                        <!--0 to 1 occurrence--><xs:id xmlns:xs="http://samples.esb.wso2.org/xsd">$2</xs:id>
                        <!--0 to 1 occurrence--><xs:name xmlns:xs="http://samples.esb.wso2.org/xsd">$3</xs:name>
                     </ax25:personInfo>
                  </ax25:info>
               </p:credit>
            </format>
            <args>
               <arg evaluator="xml" expression="$ctx:address"/>
               <arg evaluator="xml" expression="$ctx:id"/>
               <arg evaluator="xml" expression="$ctx:name"/>
            </args>
         </payloadFactory>
         <send buildmessage="true">
            <endpoint>
               <address uri="http://127.0.0.1:9764/services/CreditService/"/>
            </endpoint>
         </send>
      </outSequence>
      <endpoint>
         <address uri="http://127.0.0.1:9764/services/PersonInfoService/"/>
      </endpoint>
   </target>
   <publishWSDL uri="file:./repository/samples/resources/proxy/CreditProxy.wsdl"/>
   <description/>
</proxy>
```

What can be the reason for this?

Comment: Could you add a log level="full" after the payloadFactory inside your outSequence and add properties inside this log to show us the values of address, id and name

Comment: Hi Jean-Michel, Issue has already been resolved. Thanks for your feedback though.